# Angular Error: Element implicitly has an 'any'

Tags: angular, chromium, cefsharp

I have a code line in my Angular 9 service ctor as "window['className'] = this;", there is no problem and it works w/ a winForm app based on cef sharp.

However, in Angular 12, the same code line (window['className'] = this;) report build error. The error message is `TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'`.

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OCPCommunicationService {
  systemConfiguration$ = new BehaviorSubject('');
  constructor(private window: Window, private zone: NgZone) {
    window['OCPCommunicationService'] = this;
  }

  extSetConfiguration(systemConfiguration: string): void {
    this.systemConfiguration$.next(systemConfiguration);
    console.log('extSetConfiguration(): systemConfiguration', systemConfiguration);
  }
  public getConfiguratio(): string {
    return this.systemConfiguration$.getValue();
  }

}
```

What could be the issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a TypeScript error to alert you that it doesn't know the properties you're setting. Try something like the following

```js
(this.window as any)['OCPCommunicationService'] = this;
```

Comment: This makes the compiler happy. The OCPCommunicationService and methods can be invoked in the browser. So it works. Thanks!